# Using additional features while indexing in Approximate Nearest Neighbors

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

I am trying to develop a recommender system that suggests top 10 workers suitable for a task at hand. For the features, I have work type, criticality and location of work in both my historical and query data. I am indexing my historical data using Approximate Nearest Neighbors Oh Yeah (ANNOY) and getting the nearest neighbors of the query data. Now, I do have worker location and skillset details in the historical data that I would like to use, but this information is not present in the query data. Any leads on how I could use these extra features?